# Silverstripe - Blog post ordering

Tags: sorting, blogs, silverstripe

Thought this would be fairly easy but I seem to be struggling with this.

How does the Silverstripe blog sort its posts? I want to pin a specific blog post to the top of the list so I created a SortOrder field and gave it a value of 1. Tried to sort by SortOrder and then by PublishDate but it only seems to sort by PublishDate all the time.

Even changing this on the blog model doesn't do anything:

```
private static $default_sort = '"PublishDate" IS NULL DESC, "PublishDate" DESC' ;
```

Comment: Updating default_sort should work, eg `BlogPost: default_sort: 'SortOrder DESC, PublishDate DESC'` in your config.yml. Then setting `SortOrder` to 1 for your stickied post should place it at the top, assuming the other BlogPosts have lower values. Make sure `BlogPost_Live.SortOrder` is set to 1 -- works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating the `default_sort` of `BlogPost`should work:

```yml
# In your config.yml
BlogPost:
  default_sort: 'Sticky DESC, PublishDate DESC'
  extensions:
    - MyBlogPostExtension
```

Extend BlogPost to add a `Sticky` boolean (this could also be an `Int`):

```php
class MyBlogPostExtension extends DataExtension
{

    private static $db = [
        'Sticky' => 'Boolean'
    ];

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)
    {
        $stickyField = CheckboxField::create(
            'Sticky',
            'Sticky this blogpost'
        );

        $fields->addFieldToTab(
            'Root.Main',
            $stickyField
        );
    }

}
```

Make sure that the `BlogPost` you want stickied is published with `Sticky` set to true.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with blog, sort & lumberjack (Post in GridField not Sitetree) a bit. I use heyday/silverstripe-gridfieldversionedorderablerows to have it manually sortable.

```
Injector:
  GridFieldConfig_BlogPost:
    class: GridFieldConfig_MyBlogPost

<?php
class GridFieldConfig_MyBlogPost extends GridFieldConfig_BlogPost
{
    public function __construct($itemsPerPage = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($itemsPerPage);
        $this->addComponent(new GridFieldVersionedOrderableRows('Sort'));
        $this->getComponentByType("GridFieldPaginator")->setItemsPerPage(100);
        $this->getComponentByType("GridFieldDataColumns")->setDisplayFields(array(
            "BlogThumbnail" => "Thumbnail",
            "Title" => "Title"
        ));
    }
}
```

I made my own PaginatedListSorted on a DataExtension of Blog but you probable just could set sort as Janne Klouman suggested per yml.