# Silverstripe drag and drop reorder

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a website running silverstripe 3.6.1 with blog module 2.4.

I want to add drag and drop reordering to the blogposts Gridfield with GridFieldSortableRows and I'm not sure how to approach this.

Note: I have extended Blog and BlogPost, I have News and NewsPost, so I can add customizations of my own.

I am just looking at

```
$gridField = new BlogFilter_GridField(
    'ChildPages',
    $this->getLumberjackTitle(),
    $pages,
    $this->getLumberjackGridFieldConfig()
);
```

I have tried to add ->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('ID') after the Lumberjack config but doesn't seem to be working ( I also added SortID field to the NewsPost).

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT1:**
I'm not sure it's ok but what I've done so far, I have created a NewsFilter.php, and I removed the BlogFilter from News and replaced with NewsFilter.php so I can cleanly edit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247905/silverstripe-blog-post-ordering/43278267#43278267

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$gridFieldConfig = $this->getLumberjackGridFieldConfig();
$gridFieldConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldSortableRows('SortID')

$gridField = new BlogFilter_GridField(
    'ChildPages',
    $this->getLumberjackTitle(),
    $pages,
    $gridFieldConfig
);
```

Comment: Hi @balasz_bohonyi, first of all thank you for you answer, actually I solved this one some time ago on my own. I don't really remember how I have eventually done it. :D